# Child pages and sub-pages do not appear. Why?

Tags: child-pages

I have created a child page. However, when I access "http://example.com/Page/ChildPage" does not appear?

Page (filename = page.php -> content-page.php) [WORK]

Child Page (filename = page.php -> content-child-page.php) [NOT WORK]

page.php

```
$slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );
echo $slug;


while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content' , $slug );

endwhile; // End of the loop.
```

[image: Admin screen for all page]

[image: View donation page]

[image: Child page from donation. When clicking on the child page is redirected to the homepage]

[image: page.php]

[image: content-payment.php]

Comment: The `$slug` is child-page?

Comment: The $slug is get current page. There is something wrong?

Comment: What? when you do `echo $slug;` what do you see?

Comment: slug from Page.

Comment: Is there a different way to get slug for child page? I think that's how it works.

Comment: You want to display the `content-page.php` for every page that is not a child and to display `content-child-page.php` for every child?

Comment: Yep, I want to display content on a child page.

Comment: But there is no action to page.php when accessing child page. I have tried it. And then, direct to homepage.

Comment: Did you tried the answer? comment on the answer if thats what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the page have parent to display the child page template or if he doesnt have to display the parent page template. If `$post->post_parent` is equal to 0 thats mean that he doesnt have a parent.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $template = ($post->post_parent == 0) ? 'page' : 'child-page';
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content' , $template );
endwhile; // End of the loop.
```

Comment: The problem is the child page does not read the file from page.php

Comment: When you enter the child page what happend? do you see the `echo $slug;` output? You maybe select different page template in the child page?

Comment: Nothing appears (including echo $ slug).

Comment: Need to see some screenshots of your edit and view for the child page and the child page view source code

Comment: I have added some source code and screenshoot. I hope this help.

Comment: What is the body classes when you enter the payment page?

Comment: "home blog logged-in hfeed"